# jQuery autocomplete AJAX call doesn't work on 2nd match on select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using autocomplete j query to suggest my users some questions and then when user select one of the questions it should shows the answer.

it works fine for the first click

[image]

when user clicks on each of these questions the answer is showing correctly but the problem is when user clear the inputs and write another word and then select one of the suggestion for the next time nothing happened after select each one

here is my jquery codes

```
 $("#tags").autocomplete({

    source: function (request, response) {

        $.ajax({

            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                q: request.term
            },
            url: 'Help_And_Customer_Support/AjaxQuestion/q',
            success: function (data) {

                console.log(data.Qu);


                response($.map(data, function (item) {


                    console.log(item.Ans);
                    return { label: item.Qu, id: item.Ans };
                }))
            },

        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $("#showansw").css("height", 200);
        var qans = ui.item.id;
        var qq = ui.item.label;

        $("#showansw p").html(qans);
        $("#showansw h5").html(qq);


    }


});
```

Appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle showing a working demo?

Comment: Autocomplete documentation : `You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.` => Add failed and/or always handler which call `response(...)` in your `$.ajax` function

Comment: @Fefux thank you as you mentioned and I read documentation again the problem should be exactly there . is it possible to help me more by answering the question ? because I'm a little confused what to do exactly

Comment: Try to add after success {...}, => `error: function(req, status, error) { response([]); }` and tell me if it works

Comment: @Fefux thank you so much but still no it dosn't work

Comment: What each console.log tell you?